# ORMLite OpenDbConnection gives AccessViolationException

Tags: database, oracle, connection, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using ServiceStack and OrmLite.Oracle.  I connect to an old Oracle 7.3 instance using ODBC Driver for Oracle on a Windows Server 2012 x64.  ODBC is setup as an ODBC32.

I connect and query the database from my repo like this:

```
using (IDbConnection db = _context.DbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
    {
      return db.Select<T>();
    }
```

The _context hold the OrmLiteConnectionFactory which was created like this:

```
DbFactory= new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(conInfo.ConnectionString,false, ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle.OracleDialect.Provider);
```

My service is running just fine and I can access and query the database, no problem.
But after a certain period of time (30 minutes or so), the connection is lost and I have to restart my service (hosted in a Windows Service) because the call to Open the connection will give me this error: unable to allocate an environment handle.

It might be a normal thing to release the handle to the connection after a while but why it simply doesn't reconnect to it?  From OrmLite code, I can see that OpenDbConnection should return a new instance of its connection when the AutoDisposeConnection is set to True or if the internal ormLiteConnection is null.  I guess my connection is not null but not quite alive...

```
private OrmLiteConnection ormLiteConnection;
    private OrmLiteConnection OrmLiteConnection
    {
        get
        {
            if (ormLiteConnection == null)
            {
                ormLiteConnection = new OrmLiteConnection(this);
            }
            return ormLiteConnection;
        }
    }

    public IDbConnection OpenDbConnection()
    {
        var connection = CreateDbConnection();
        connection.Open();

        return connection;
    }

    public IDbConnection CreateDbConnection()
    {
        if (this.ConnectionString == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ConnectionString", "ConnectionString must be set");

        var connection = AutoDisposeConnection
            ? new OrmLiteConnection(this)
            : OrmLiteConnection;

        return connection;
    }
```

I have tried to set the AutoDisposeConnection to True but when I do, I always get an AccessViolationException saying "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.".  What does that mean?  Is this an OS, ODBC or OrmLite error?  Any idea why this is happening?

I have to say that because I am using Oracle 7.3, I had to recompile the ServiceStack.OrmLite.Oracle.dll so it uses the System.Data.Odbc rather than System.Data.OracleClient (only compatible with v8+).

I really want to avoid to test if the connection is alive or not at every call, so any help to make this work is greatly appreciated.  Thanks